# How to migrate dbase database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dbf, migrate, dbase

How to use rake with https://github.com/infused/dbf/. I tried to write in *database.yml* such text:

```
development:  
  adapter: dbf
  database: db/file.dbf
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

But it say, that didn't find adapter **activerecord-dbf-adapter**.
I need only read dbf-files.
PS. I can't use JDBC adapter.

**UPDATE**
I want to use dbf database such as another dabases (e.g. mysql) in rails with support ActiveRecord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use dbf with ActiveRecord, but that it's not what this gem does. It just provides the ability to read dbf files from Ruby.

To use it in your application you could write a class that would implement all the common methods you want and inherit from there, something like:

```
require 'dbf'
class DbfModel

  def initialize
    @table= DBF::Table.new("#{self.class.name}.dbf")
  end

  def find your_params_here
    @table.find your_params_here
  end

end
```

If do you want to use dbf with ActiveRecord you should find some adapter for it, but I haven't been lucky looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a chapter "Basic usage" on https://github.com/infused/dbf/ that answers your question.

```
require 'dbf'
table= DBF::Table.new("your_table.dbf")
```

`database.yml` is a config file to connect to databases. If you don't want to connect to a dbf-db throughout your whole rails application, you must not specify `adapter: dbf`. That's why you get this error.

I strongly recommend you to read the guides on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. Also read the gem's readme and wiki on https://github.com/infused/dbf/.

Comment: I read chapter **Migrating to ActiveRecord** in https://github.com/infused/dbf/, but I do not know what to do next - it gives an error.

Comment: do you want to read from a dbf file separately in rails OR do you want your whole rails applicatino to use a dbf database instead of e.g. mysql? Your question is a bit ambiguous

Comment: I want to use dbf database instead other database (e.g. mysql).

Comment: Have a look at cicloon's answer.